Why VLA is comparable to gets?
It is well-known that MSVC doesn't, and won't support VLA feature.
During searching MSVC online reference, I found somewhat interesting sentence:

Variable length array (VLA) support isn't planned. VLAs provide attack vectors comparable to gets, which is deprecated and planned for removal.

As far as I know, C/C++ standard function gets has been depreciated, and then removed from standard, because there is no way to control the size of input data, which becomes unavoidable security hole/attack vector.
I wonder why VLA feature is comparable to gets. At least we know size of requested data when we use VLA.
